# POST request parameters are not detected by PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to submit some data with fetch to a php backend, but no request arrives on the backend.

The following is triggered on a change event.

**JS**

```
const submitVote = async (value) => {
  const vote = { vote: value };
  console.log('vote:', vote);
  let postVote = await fetch('Backend/postHandler.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
    body: JSON.stringify(vote)
  });

  let result = await postVote.text();
  console.log('result:',result);
};
```

Logs `vote: Object { vote: "yes" }` to the console.

On the backend

**PHP**

```
<?php 
namespace WebPoll\Backend;

if(isset( $_POST['vote'] )) {
  $a = ["vote" => $_POST['vote']];
  $myJSON = json_encode($a);
  echo $myJSON;
} else {
  print_r($_POST);
}
```

Logs `result: array()` to the JS console.

What is wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: is there is any error in your `console` ?

Comment: nothing was sent to backend

Comment: No errors in the console. If nothing is sent to the backend, what is wrong with the fetch post?

Comment: try to edit your headers to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` only without `charset=utf-8`

Comment: check this example it may help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options

Comment: Joseph, Thanks for the link. While I was studying it, I found the example had a commented out line `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',` instead of `application/json`. I'm not too sure of the difference between the two yet, but changing that line worked.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, it makes sense as php is expecting form data, not just json data.

Comment: At least I'm getting `result: Array
(
    [{"vote":"yes"}] => 
)` returned. So it's not yet a $_POST variable, but it's a start.

Comment: Ok, I think I have it sorted. From the Mozilla link, it seems to work if I follow the steps under the "Uploading a file" section. It's a bit weird though. I don't quite get it yet.

Comment: The posted body data might not be put into `$_POST`. Maybe this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300194/4946451